# Zend form application

Tags: forms, zend-framework

Im writing a program in zend using zend forms. Everything is fine the form process well to the database but the problem is that the form is too long +-50 inputs which all belong to one database table. How can I find a way to shorten/break some parts of the form to fill in first and then use a next link to fill the rest, bit by bit, and then a finish link to process the form to the database. Basically break the form in parts so that the user wont give up easily or become lazy while filling in his/her details. Can I use multipage form if so, how can I go about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As each step will probably contain its own validation, I suppose that the best approach would be to write a separate form for each step in the wizard. After successful validation of one form, store the results in the session and proceed to the next step.

Comment: I tried the problem is the second data creates a new id in the database any solutions

Comment: please check my latest post

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. The idea was _not_ to write the data into the DB between the steps. Instead, store it in the session (or memcached, or ...). Only save at the last step when your record is complete.

Comment: Please check my latest post and review my code im kinda lost here at the moment maybe u might have a clear understanding. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979546/zendform-related

Answer (score 0):

Use Sub forms for each step (page). See this example - http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.advanced.html#zend.form.advanced.multiPage

Comment: Thanks for the help but multi-forms only allow more than one form at a page I want to process the forms step by step using a next or save and continue link.here is my question I edited it a bit now stackoverflow.com/questions/19979546/zendform-related –  Programmer man